# bootstrap-sass not minifying with Gulp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, gulp

Trying to use Bootstrap SASS with Gulp JS.  Used the same setup with Foundation and no troubles, but Bootstrap scss partials will not minify. The style.css file is created, but will not minified.

Running sass -v 3.4.11 and Bootstrap-sass is 3.3.3.

Gulp sass processing section is this:

```
// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe(plugins.rubySass({ style: 'compressed', sourcemap: true }))
    .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer('last 2 versions', 'ie 9', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/styles/build'))
    .pipe(plugins.minifyCss({ keepSpecialComments: 1 }))
    .pipe(plugins.livereload(server))
    .pipe(cmq({log: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    .pipe(plugins.notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});
```

And for some reason the style.css won't minify.

Any ideas, I've run out?

Comment: Redid my gulp styles task and took out the livereload since using browser sync and that seemed to solve the problem.